# overloaded methods in java

Tags: java, overloading

I have a misunderstanding with overloaded methods in Java.

Are these overloaded or not?

1. `public String eJava(int age, String name, double duration);`
2. `float eJava(double name, String age, byte duration);`

In test that i wrote the answer is YES. But i don't think so.
Reason: 
Let's take an example of method arguments: eJava(111, "word", 222);

Those arguments can be passed to both methods, as i know. Because 111 can be accepted by double and int, "word" is accepted by String and 222 can be accepted by byte or double. So i think that correct answer is "compilation error".

Ok, those methods have different return types, but that is not important.

What am i doing wrong?
Thank You

Comment: Yes, this is a correct example of method overloading. And no, your assumption that it wouldn't compile is wrong. You call it with `eJava(111, "word", 222);`. Here, `111` is an `int`, so the method with `int age` as first parameter will be called.

Comment: @apomene already answered you correctly. They are overloaded methods

Comment: @BackSlash that's not the reason the call would not be ambiguous. It's because `int` cannot be implicitly converted to `byte` for the 3rd argument of the second method, so only the first method can be called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they are overloaded methods, because they have the same name but different argument types. apomeme's answer gives more detail.

To answer the second question:

Your call `eJava(111, "word", 222)` is not ambiguous, and not a compilation error. It matches the first method: `eJava(int age, String name, double duration)`. It cannot match the second method, because its third argument is a byte, and an int literal cannot be implicitly converted to a byte. Such narrowing conversions are disallowed unless you explicitly cast them.

However, if the second method was

```
float eJava(double name, String age, long duration)
```

then the call would indeed be ambiguous and a compilation error, because an int literal *can* be implicitly converted to long.

Comment: Thank You! I didn't know that byte can't be automatically converted to byte. :)

Comment: @mislav23 actually, 222 can't possibly be a byte literal because bytes have values ranging from -128 to 127. 222 is outside that range.

Comment: ohhhh yes, my fault. But if it is a number 100? Still would be compilation error because 100 cant' be implicitly converted to byte?

Comment: Integral literals are of type `int` unless followed by `L` which makes them of type long. If you want them to be anything else, you have to cast them. But you can also use int literals when initializing short and byte variables.

Answer (score 5):

Going by definition:

> If a class has multiple methods having same name but different in
>   parameters, it is known as Method Overloading.  There are two ways to
>   overload the method in java
>
> ```
> By changing number of arguments
> By changing the data type
> ```

So the correct answer is YES, those are two overloaded methods

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou has correct answer. Your answer is not 100% truth. Becouse:

public String eJava(int age, String name, double duration);
float eJava(double name, String age, long duration);

That would be compilation error. Arguments (111, "word", 222) can be accepted by both methods and that is error.

Comment: @mislav23 apomene's answer is 100% correct for the first part of the question. My answer covers the second part, which is about the call, not the overload set. Note that the declaration of two overloaded methods you mention in your comment is not a compilation error. The compilation error is only in that particular method call. It's the call that's ambiguous, not the methods.

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou yes... Your example is still overloaded method, but it is not correctly overloaded method. Because question in my test was: "Given the following signature of method eJava, choose the options that correctly
overload this method....."

Answer (score 0):

A class may have more than one method with the same name, but
with different argument lists. This is called method overloading.
For example:
 **method with the same names:**
`System.out.println("Hello")`-->with type String
`System.out.println(4+8)`-->with type int
`System.out.println("I have"+100+"$")`--> with type String + int
**second example:**
 **method with the same names:**

`int size(int height,int width)`--two type in parameter
`int size(int distance)`-->one type in peremeter.

Comment: The question did not ask "What is method overloading". It asked about the specific scenario given as you can see by the question "Are these overloaded or not?"

Comment: When I say argument list, I am not talking about return type of the method, for example if two methods have same name, same parameters and have different return type, then this is not a valid method overloading example. This will throw compilation error.<br>int add(int, int)
<br>float add(int, int)